# How to expand Range of Array in Sheets based on column height

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a custom formula that gets the redirect of a link. It takes an array as an argument. Its based on a Google script found here. [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvi18.png)

The problem is that the source list gets updated and the range changes. If the range isn't exact, it breaks. Here is the code to the custom function:

```
function DOUBLE(input) {
  return input.map(getRedirects);
}

function getRedirects(input) {
    var urlKey = input;
    var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
    var result = cache.get(urlKey);

    if (!result) {
        var params = {
            'followRedirects': false,
            'muteHttpExceptions': true
        };
        var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(input, params);
        var finalURL = res.getHeaders()['Location'];

        cache.put(urlKey, finalURL, 21600);
        
        result = finalURL;
    }

    return result;
}
```

[image: code working]
[image: code not working]

And here's the spreadsheet: [working sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xigMp9ADAe2f4w-MoZQPVHX2qaiCsFNTiTmDjFWxi7U/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out. Wrap this in a try .. catch block. The UrlFetchApp fails when it gets an empty input. When this is the case the catch block kicks in. Other option is writing an if statement. if input is not '' then do the fetch and return, else.. ect.

```
function DOUBLE(input) {
  return input.map(getRedirects);
}

function getRedirects(input) {
  var params = {
    'followRedirects': false,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };

  try {
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(input, params);
  var finalURL = res.getHeaders()['Location'];

  return finalURL

  } catch(error){
    return undefined
  }
}
```

EDIT ("normal" function): *(Why is my code block like that? I even tried to use a online beautifier...)*

1. Select the range in your sheet
2. Custom menu "Redirects" -> Run
3. Output is placed in the column next to it.

```
    function onOpen(e) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Redirects')
            .addItem('run', 'getRedirects')
            .addToUi()
    }
    
    function getRedirects() {
        const activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()
        const values = activeRange.getValues().flat()
    
        const output = []
    
        const params = {
            'followRedirects': false,
            'muteHttpExceptions': true
        };
    
        values.forEach(url => {
            try {
                const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
                const finalURL = res.getHeaders()['Location'];
                output.push([finalURL])
    
            } catch (error) {
                output.push([JSON.stringify(error)])
            }
        });
    
        activeRange.offset(0, 1).setValues(output)
    }
```

Comment: Thx. the first one is working good, but it turns out custom functions time out too quickly. I'm told if I make it executable and run it manually/triggered, it won't time out for like 5-6 minutes. Can I manually replace "input" a range?

Comment: I edited the post. I don't know why my formatting is so weird..

Comment: Thx. The second solution works, but it still times out with just a couple hundred rows

Comment: Yes. Fetching urls is not that fast... But with this solution you can split things up. Or upgrade so you have a 30 min runtime...